# Vf page not showing the output

Tags: visualforce, wrapper-class

I have written wrapper class.

But the visualforce page is not showing the output.

```
public class Task17empadd {
    public Task17employee emp {set;get;}
    public Task17address  addr {set;get;}
    public Task17empadd(){
     emp = new    Task17employee();
     addr= new Task17address();
           }
    public void setempdata(){
        emp.name='Mai';
        emp.salary=40000;
        emp.technology='Java';
        emp.exp=4.5;
    }
    public void setaddrdata(){
        addr.city='Hyd';
        addr.place='hjjh';
        addr.state='UP';
        addr.pincode='698899';
    }
}
```

==================
VF page is

```
<apex:page controller="Task17empadd">
    Name    :   {!emp.name}<br/><br/>
    Salary  :   {!emp.salary}<br/><br/>
    Technology: {!emp.technology}<br/><br/>
    Experience: {!emp.exp}<br/><br/>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Task 17 eh? This question looks suspiciously like it is for an interview.

Answer (score 0):

Your `setempdata` and `setaddrdata` don't get called unless you explicitly call them from Apex, or set them from Visualforce. You can only set primitives from the latter, so it would only pass in a value if you called `setempdata` in your constructor. So you can call those methods from your constructor or, better yet, move the your setting of those properties into it instead.